# second expansion of make variables

Tags: gnu-make, expansion, makefile

I have a makefile like below. There are some files say `x.c`,`x.h` in current dir. and additionally I am generating some source/header files from a python script under a target `code_gen`. After generating , I build them .

Once I have  generated the files, I don't want to generate them again with make all. I will generate only if the one or more generated files are missing.

```
#predefine list of generated src files.
GEN_SRC_FILES := a.c b.c d.c
GEN_HEADER_FILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.h,$(GEN_SRC_FILES))
GEN_FILES_LIST += $(GEN_SRC_FILES) $(GEN_HEADER_FILES)

#Get all source and header currently in dir.
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
HEADER := $(wildcard *.h)

#Get list of generated source and header files currently existing in dir.
GEN_SRC_FILES_TEMP := $(filter $(GEN_SRC_FILES), $(SRC))
GEN_HEADER_FILES_TEMP := $(filter $(GEN_HEADER_FILES), $(HEADER))
GEN_FILES_LIST_TEMP += $(GEN_SRC_FILES_TEMP) $(GEN_HEADER_FILES_TEMP)

OBJECT_FILES :=$(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))
OBJ := $(patsubst %, $(BUILD_DIR)/%, $(OBJECT_FILES))
CLEAN_OBJECTS := $(OBJ)

ifneq ($(GEN_FILES_LIST_TEMP),$(GEN_FILES_LIST))
all:code_gen lib
else
all:lib
endif
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH)

lib: $(BUILD_DIR)/lib_x.a

$(BUILD_DIR)/lib_x.a: $(OBJ)
        $(AR) $(ARCHIVE_OPTIONS) $(BUILD_DIR)/lib_x.a $(OBJ)

code_gen:
        python ../../my_script.py
```

Problem is first time when I am generating the files :

```
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
HEADER := $(wildcard *.h)
```

This only has existing .c/.h files - `x.c /x.h`  during the first time invocation of `make`. so when `code_gen` target is done

```
OBJECT_FILES :=$(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))
OBJ := $(patsubst %, $(BUILD_DIR)/%, $(OBJECT_FILES))
```

This points to `x.o`  only but now there are new files `a.c,b.c,d.c`.
`obj` should ideally be `x.o a.o b.o d.o`. 
How can I force second time expansion of `SRC`,`OBJ` ?
I tried `.SECONDEXPANSION` but not able to get its syntax correct . Is there any other method to do this ?
Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let make do its job the natural way, that is, discover that some C files are missing and tell it how to generate them (but read also the important note that follows):

```
GEN_SRC_FILES    := a.c b.c d.c
GEN_HEADER_FILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.h,$(GEN_SRC_FILES))
SRC              := $(sort $(wildcard *.c) $(GEN_SRC_FILES))
OBJ              := $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC))

.PRECIOUS: $(GEN_SRC_FILES) $(GEN_HEADER_FILES)

all: lib

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH)

lib: $(BUILD_DIR)/lib_x.a

$(BUILD_DIR)/lib_x.a: $(OBJ)
    $(AR) $(ARCHIVE_OPTIONS) $@ $^

$(GEN_SRC_FILES) $(GEN_HEADER_FILES):
    python ../../my_script.py
```

(`sort` not only sorts the words passed as arguments but also removes duplicates). Note that I added the headers in the prerequisites list for compilation and that I changed the `$^` automatic variable to `$<` (first prerequisite) in the corresponding recipe. Note also that I used automatic variables everywhere they could be. Finally, I added a `.PRECIOUS` rule to protect the generated files from automatic deletion. Adapt to your needs.

**Important note**: there is a drawback to this solution. If you run make in parallel (e.g. `make -j4`) you will probably see that the python script is run several times. This is because make does not know that one single run creates all missing source files. And this is annoying not just because of performance but also because it could create race conditions between the python script and the compiler. Unfortunately there is still no straightforward way to tell make that one recipe produces several files. But there is a specificity of pattern rules that could be used there: for pattern rules with several targets make considers that all targets are produced by one single execution of the recipe. From GNU make manual:

> Pattern rules may have more than one target. Unlike normal rules, this does not act as many different rules with the same prerequisites and recipe. If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the rule’s recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets. When searching for a pattern rule to match a target, the target patterns of a rule other than the one that matches the target in need of a rule are incidental: make worries only about giving a recipe and prerequisites to the file presently in question. However, when this file’s recipe is run, the other targets are marked as having been updated themselves.

So, if you can represent the source files generation with a pattern rule like:

```
foo%.c bar%.c baz%.c foo%.h bar%.h baz%.h:
    ...
```

(where the `%` wildcard **must match at least one character**), you are done. In your case you could for instance rename the generated files `{a,b,d}_gen.c`:

```
GEN_SRC_FILES := a_gen.c b_gen.c d_gen.c)
...
a_g%n.c b_g%n.c d_g%n.c a_g%n.h b_g%n.h d_g%n.h:
    python ../../my_script.py
```

Of course, automating the creation of the targets list would be better. In order to do this, we will exploit the fact that make `patsubst` function substitutes only the first `%` found in the replacement string:

```
$(patsubst %_gen.c,%_g%n.c,$(GEN_SRC_FILES)) $(patsubst %_gen.h,%_g%n.h,$(GEN_HEADER_FILES)):
    python ../../my_script.py
```

If this renaming is not an option and you cannot find a pattern rule that would do the job there is one last possibility: recursive make (make invoking make):

```
GEN_SRC_FILES    := a.c b.c d.c
GEN_HEADER_FILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.h,$(GEN_SRC_FILES))
GEN_FILES        := $(GEN_SRC_FILES) $(GEN_HEADER_FILES)
SRC              := $(sort $(wildcard *.c) $(GEN_SRC_FILES))
OBJ              := $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC))

ifneq ($(sort $(wildcard $(GEN_FILES))),$(sort $(GEN_FILES)))
all:
    python ../../my_script.py
    $(MAKE)
else
all: lib

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH)

lib: $(BUILD_DIR)/lib_x.a

$(BUILD_DIR)/lib_x.a: $(OBJ)
    $(AR) $(ARCHIVE_OPTIONS) $@ $^
endif
```

One last note: it would be even better to tell make that the generated source files depend on their prerequisites (the python script, plus some other data files, maybe):

```
$(GEN_SRC_FILES) $(GEN_HEADER_FILES): ../../my_script.py ../../my_data_file.txt
    python $<
```

or:

```
$(patsubst %_gen.c,%_g%n.c,$(GEN_SRC_FILES)) $(patsubst %_gen.h,%_g%n.h,$(GEN_HEADER_FILES)): ../../my_script.py ../../my_data_file.txt
    python $<
```

But combining this last improvement with the recursive make solution is tricky (and left as an exercise...)

Comment: Wow, what an answer !! More i read this more i feel that when i become as good as you guys there.Thanks a ton.